# Help identify this SMD oscillator

Tags: fpga, identification, surface-mount, hdmi

This oscillator provides clock to an FPGA which powers the ultrahdmi mod for an N64 (https://www.retrorgb.com/ultrahdmi.html).
It's clearly marked
A03ZZ
1414

Clock output is diametrically opposite pin 1, it's a 4 pin device, it takes a 3.3V supply. Dimensions are nominally 3.2mm by 2.5mm

When I scope it with my limited equipment I get a weak ~75MHz signal (50mv p-p), but that could be junk from a number of sources.

[image: 4 pin SMD osc A03ZZ 1414]

The story behind this: it came to me with a glitch where it would lose on screen display functionality over time. Careful application of compressed air suggested the oscillator was the culprit, so I tapped it with the soldering iron on all 4 corners - now the device simply doesn't work. I've since fixed the bridge between the land and the exposed leadframe to no avail. I'd  like to try replacing this part with something as close as possible, but if we fail to identify it SMD oscillators are cheap enough that I'll buy a spread of spectrum and try em all if I have to.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [this Abracon](https://abracon.com/datasheets/AMPD.pdf) programmable MEMS oscillator with 40/80MHz outputs but the markings are not necessarily a match.

You could also try asking the manufacturer very nicely, or phoning them (harder to say no).

Comment: I concur it's probably a MEMS oscillator, the packaging looks right, unfortunately since the markings don't align I can't use them to determine the frequency. I've tried reaching out to the manufacturer but there's no contact information - I've reached out to the reseller to try and get more information. It's becoming likely that I'll simply jam in a few oscillators until I get close and can science it out.